# Calling vbscript for informatica command task

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, informatica

I have a vbscript which takes two parameters to convert an xlsx file to csv file.
Now, I want to call this .vbs from informatica command task. I tried calling it using cscript. I even tried creating a .bat file and then calling it, but it is not working.
Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If your Informatica server is Linux, `wine` should allow you to run Windows applications from the Linux shell:

```
wine cscript MyScript.vbs
```

or

```
wine wscript MyScript.vbs
```

https://www.winehq.org/